# Unity launcher -- is it available as a separate package?

Tags: unity, dock

Is the launcher (side dock) found in Unity available as a stand-alone package that can be added to other desktops? (like xfce)

If so, what's the package name? and is it available for 10.04 or only 10.10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unity is available for 10.10, you just need to install the ubuntu-netbook package

Unity is also available for 10.04 through the PPA named canonical-dx-team/+archive/une

In both cases this will add a new "Netbook edition" option in the login screen. **I don't think the dock is available as a stand-alone package.**

More information and detailled installation instructions can be found on the wiki :
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopTeam/Unity

Comment: Please note that Unity's PPA pulls some system library updates which are required for the Unity dock.

Answer (score 2):

The 2D Unity project comes with `unity-2d-launcher` which can serve as a stand-alone unity launcher

PPA: https://launchpad.net/~unity-2d-team/+archive/unity-2d-daily

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Unite theme](http://bigrza.deviantart.com/art/Unite-for-DockbarX-165172732) for [dockbarx](https://edge.launchpad.net/dockbar) that is intended to replicate Unity. Dockbarx is [available in a PPA](https://edge.launchpad.net/~dockbar-main/+archive/ppa) although you will have to install the theme seperately.

[image: Unite theme for dockbarx]