# Unity launcher in Desktop Edition?

Tags: 10.10, unity, dock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity launcher — is it available as a separate package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308/unity-launcher-is-it-available-as-a-separate-package)

Is it possible just to get the unity launcher - JUST be the unity **launcher** - in desktop edition? As an alternative to Avant, Docky or Gnome Do?

*Update: I would just to point out that we now know the 11.04 desktop edition with have the Unity interface by default!*

Comment: Just for clarity: 11.04 Desktop edition will use a desktop version of unity's current interface. But you're probably correct in that it will have the dock. I looking forward to this, just hope it's as good as dockbarX.=)

Comment: And by the way, would you mind changing your all-caps to an emphasized? (ctrl+i)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [Unite theme](http://bigrza.deviantart.com/art/Unite-for-DockbarX-165172732) for [dockbarx](https://edge.launchpad.net/dockbar) that is intended to replicate Unity. Dockbarx is [available in a PPA](https://edge.launchpad.net/~dockbar-main/+archive/ppa) although you will have to install the theme seperately.

[image: Unite theme for dockbarx]

Comment: What GTK theme are you using? and what kind of notification i sthat?

Comment: It's a [Black Elementary theme](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/black-element?content=124850). That isn't 'my' screenshot though, but the [original poster's comments](http://bigrza.deviantart.com/art/Unite-for-DockbarX-165172732?offset=0#comments) suggest the notification is to do with CoverGloobus.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the unity dock is the dockbarx applet, make sure you install the extra themes so get the unity themes (assuming you are using Ubuntu 10.10, an `'apt-get install ubuntu-netbook'`)

This is the PPA link:
https://launchpad.net/~dockbar-main/+archive/ppa

You can find more useful information about dockbarx:
http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/DockbarX?content=101604
And be sure to check out this Ubuntu Forum thread:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9968108

Comment: apt-getting the entire ubuntu-netbook install is really way above his needs.